# timelapse avi video shows frames not timecode

Tags: time-lapse, premiere

I have to splice together some timelapse files from a new Brinno HD camera and add a title. Pretty simple. The Brinno cameras automatically produce AVI files. When I import the files into PremierePro, letting PremierePro create the sequence settings, the timeline shows frames and not timecode. Sequence settings showed a timebase of 10 frames per second and the timeline displays only frames and only frames is available for display in sequence settings. I changed the timebase to 24 fps and the other options become available and I can display timecode in the timeline. Also, the clips change from white to purple in the timeline. Is there anything wrong with doing this? I am pretty new to video and timelapse work.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly is your problem? If your workflow is fine and you can accomplish your task, then colours and display settings do not really matter.